# Getting correct data from X/Y Coords within certain range BUT including Width & Height

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, mariadb, coordinates

I'm writing radar logic that finds the nearby objects and then displays them in a 'radar' window as such:

[image]

The logic (That works!) is as shows - slightly simplified from the original:

```
 -- 5000 = radar distance
 -- Width can be called from a.width
 -- Height can be called from a.height
```

.

```
select * from positions a
    inner join positions b on b.user_id = :user_id
    left join users u on a.user_id = u.id
where 1=1
and (
    a.x >= (b.x - 5000)
 && a.x <= (b.x + 5000)
 && a.y >= (b.y - 5000)
 && a.y <= (b.y + 5000)
)
```

The problem I have is that some objects are very large. I.e. larger than even the radar distance. This means that if the center point of the large object creeps out of the radar distance, the whole object goes even if the height/width still would span within the radar distance.

Here is an example of the problem (Moving left causes the yellow shape to disappear even though it is still technically in radar view distance however the center point of the object left the radar distance causing it to not show in the sql results):

[image]

I hope I have explained myself well enough to be understood. Here are my attempts to resolve this issue myself (None I've manged to get working):

*Failed attempt #1:*

```
select * from positions a
    inner join positions b on b.user_id = 10
    left join users u on a.user_id = u.id
where 1=1
and (
    a.x >= ((b.x+a.width) - 5000)
 && a.x <= ((b.x-a.width) + 5000)
 && a.y >= ((b.y+a.height) - 5000)
 && a.y <= ((b.y+a.height) + 5000)
)
```

*Failed attempt #2:*

```
select * from positions a
    inner join positions b on b.user_id = 10
    left join users u on a.user_id = u.id
where 1=1
and (
    a.x >= (b.x - 5000)
 && a.x <= (b.x + 5000)
 && a.y >= (b.y - 5000)
 && a.y <= (b.y + 5000)
)
OR (
    (a.x+a.width) >= ((b.x+a.width) - 5000)
 && (a.x-a.width) <= ((b.x-a.width) + 5000)
 && (a.y+a.height) >= ((b.y+a.height) - 5000)
 && (a.y-a.height) <= ((b.y+a.height) + 5000)
)
```

I think I'm getting to the point where I'm starting to confuse myself. Please do let me know if you need any additional information.

Thank you for considering my question

---

**More thorough example:**

Every object has a height/width/x/y coordinate as such:

```
+----+------+------+--------+-------+
| id |  x   |  y   | height | width |
+----+------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 |  100 |  100 |    150 |   150 |
|  2 | -250 |  500 |    150 |   150 |
|  3 | 5000 | 2000 |  10000 | 10000 |
+----+------+------+--------+-------+
```

Imagine there is an arbitrary 'radar distance' set to 5,000.

If I am sitting at coordinates: `0x, 0y` I can see `ID3`. If I move to coordinates: `-100x, 0y` my SQL no longer retrieves the `ID3` because the central point of the coordinates expands outside the 5,000 radar distance. However - the width expands 50% into the radar and the height expands 50% into the radar which means the object should still be seen and retrieved via SQL.

**[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kZj23yzVDxF93K6AL9ek6/2) (Change `-100` to `0` and you will see the large object in the returned data again)**

Comment: You basically want to return all object that are in the intersection of a circle (radar's effective range in 2D) and any 2D object you have in your database. This is exactly what the geospatial extension of mysql / mariadb is for. Have you considered using this extension?

Comment: Hi Shadow, thank you for your reply but I'm sorry I cannot use any extensions for this problem. The radar distance is actually a square intersection and the yellow shape is also a square just with border-radius set to it. I'm still trying to work this out with pure sql logic. Cheers

Comment: Spatial extension is built into mysql / mariadb. If you have the right version installed, then the functions are there for you to use. Since these functions and data types are part of mysql and mariad, using them means using pure sql logic.

Comment: Ty for forwarding me - I'm trying to read through the docs now

Comment: @Strawberry As I have already stated at the beginning of the question, I simplified the query for this question. My original query is obviously not `Select *` because of this. The SQL Fiddle should be enough for one to go with & all queries in this question still work as intended even with the *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I worked out the answer to my question. I think this does the job:

```
set @my_x = -100;
set @my_y = 0;
set @radar_distance = 5000;

select * from positions a
where 1=1
and (
    a.x >= (@my_x - @radar_distance)
 && a.x <= (@my_x + @radar_distance)
 && a.y >= (@my_y - @radar_distance)
 && a.y <= (@my_y + @radar_distance)
)
or (
    a.x+(a.width/2) >= (@my_x - @radar_distance)
 && a.x-(a.width/2) <= (@my_x + @radar_distance)
 && a.y+(a.height/2) >= (@my_y - @radar_distance)
 && a.y-(a.height/2) <= (@my_y + @radar_distance)
)
```

<s>Although I think, still, if the dimensions of the object stretched longer than the radar it would still break. I will be testing now</s>

Yes, this works.

I also think I can take the whole first block of conditions out before my `OR` as well. Will need to test

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2kZj23yzVDxF93K6AL9ek6/3)

Comment: Conceptually you need to expand the search area window based on the size of the object that might be visible in the window, i.e. your base window size +- half the width of the object, and see if the object's center point is in this dynamically sized window

Answer (score 0):

While using the square limits appropriately limits the data, the distance from a point needs to be the main SQL criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM positions a
INNER JOIN positions b ON b.user_id = 10
WHERE POW(a.x - b.x, 2) + POW(a.y - b.y, 2) < POW(5000,2);
```

Comment: Hi Dan - this rendition seems to mimic the original code that works but also has the seem issue where it doesn't include the data that has a height/width that expands into the radar area (If that makes any sense!) P.S. Nice hat!

Answer (score 0):

Your "width" and "height" sound like the "bounding box" approach to graphical distances.  Do you also do the Pythagorean distance as danblack suggested?

You actually have two widths and heights (or two radiuses) -- one for how far your radar stretches, one for how far each object stretches.  Something like:

```
 AND a.x >= ((b.x+a.width) - (5000 + b.width))
 AND a.x <= ((b.x-a.width) + (5000 + b.width))
 AND a.y >= ((b.y+a.height) - (5000 + b.height))
 AND a.y <= ((b.y+a.height) + (5000 + b.height))
```

This implies having a `height` and `width` (and `radius`) for each object.

Comment: Hi Rick, I'm a little confused what you mean exactly. I think *I* got a little confused when I added that example, sorry about that. I have added an SQL Fiddle hopefully showing in more detail the problem. Yes you are right though, the width and height are like the 'bounding box' of the object and the x/y is the exact center of said object. I tried Dan's answer but it doesn't seem to take width/height into the equation.